# How can I control the subreport layout?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, subreport, rdl

My business analysts have created 7 reports (using Report Builder) they want merged into a MEGA-report. I've been trying to do this by wrapping them all in subreports (which you can't use in Report Builder 1.0). While all reports show up, the layouts are all over the place. The subreports seem to reorder themselves.

I've dropped down to only using two reports to try to isolate the error. When this runs, subreport2 shows up above subreport1.

What changes do I need to make to my report, (or the child reports) to get them to display in order?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="schema">
  <InteractiveHeight>11in</InteractiveHeight>
  <rd:DrawGrid>true</rd:DrawGrid>
  <InteractiveWidth>8.5in</InteractiveWidth>
  <rd:SnapToGrid>true</rd:SnapToGrid>
  <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
  <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
  <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
  <rd:ReportID>480f6105-cb4d-4969-b530-81ab5a5e3fb8</rd:ReportID>
  <Width>8.5in</Width>
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Subreport Name="subreport1">
        <ReportName>Report1</ReportName>
      </Subreport>   
      <Subreport Name="subreport2">
        <ReportName>Report2</ReportName>
      </Subreport> 
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>0.5in</Height>
   </Body>
   <Language>en-US</Language>
   <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
  </Report>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Table
2. Place each subreport in its own table cell
3. Organize cells for desired layout